# Cmd-line usage to embed PDF search index via Acrobat Pro

Tags: pdf, automation, acrobat

I'm running Acrobat DC Pro and I have quite a lot of PDFs in which I automatically want to embed a PDF search-index to.

Manually I'm going this way: Tools -> Index -> Manage Embedded Index -> Embed Index.

[image: Example]

Is there a way to automatically do it?

I know AutoIt or AutoHotKey, but don't know whether this would be the way to go as I'm not sure whether they can read what's shown on the screen (e.g. in case the index is already embedded).

Is it possible to invoke that functionality from CMD-Line or via VBA / Powershell Scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not well-versed in the [Action Wizard](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html), however there does seem to be evidence that this is somewhat automatable at least in Acrobat DC:

Notice the 'Index' tool that can be added as an Action from the 'Go To' section:

[image: Notice the 'Index' tool that can be added as an Action]

That should allow you to open a set of PDFs and apply the Indexing action to each in successive fashion.